# how to install thermostat

Tags: thermostat

Im trying to install a new thermostat but the wires dont really line up (not sure what to do about the blue). Which wires should be connected to which?

existing thermostat and the new wires next to it

[image]

instructions diagram
[image]

Update 1

[image]

dug a little deeper and found a white cable but still not sure what todo
not to mention there are 3 blacks as well coming from the wall

Here is what im guessing at?

Red (from thermostat) goes to black that is currently going to red cable on old thermostat

Black(from thermostat) goes to the 2black wires currently going to black on old thermostat

Blue(from thermostat) goes to all three whites?

did i get the wrong thermostat?  1 pole vs 2.

Comment: It looks like you have a wifi controlled thermostat? If so, you need to also have the neutral wire, which could be in your box/opening. Basically, in the USA, our standard wires are colored white-neutral, black/red-hot/switched hot, and blue is used in fans with separate light control. You need your black to black, red to red, and you need a neutral wire for the blue, that could be a white. We need to see more in the box/opening to see what you have in there.

Comment: yes it is wifi!  ok so blue to white, cool, thanks!.  I made an update above showing more wires i found from the wall.  thing is there are multiples (and no red, the only red one is coming from old thermostat to 1 of the blacks); so thats confusing me a bit.  also you should probably turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a wifi controlled thermostat? If so, you need to also have the neutral wire, which could be in your box/opening. Basically, in the USA, our standard wires are colored white-neutral, black/red-hot/switched hot, and blue is used in fans with separate light control. You need your black to black, red to red, and you need a neutral wire for the blue, that could be a white. We need to see more in the box/opening to see what you have in there.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration worked for me:

- Red (from thermostat) goes to the black wire that was going to the red wire on the old thermostat
- Black (from thermostat) goes to the 2 black wires that were going to the black wire on old thermostat
- Blue (from thermostat) goes to all three white wires